# How to trigger AWS Lambda function when creating ELB Security Group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns

I've just created a Lambda function that updates inbound rules of my Security Group with an "AmazonIpSpaceChanged" SNS trigger that runs every time the AWS IP JSON file is updated.

I would like to know if it is possible to make this function also run when creating a Security Group? If so, do I have to go through a CloudWatch / CloudTrail event or it is possible to create an "SNS" type event in my clufdormation stack that would trigger this function (like a test event below) ?

Example of a test event that works to test the function :

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "EventVersion": "1.0",
      "EventSubscriptionArn": "arn:aws:sns:EXAMPLE",
      "EventSource": "aws:sns",
      "Sns": {
        "SignatureVersion": "1",
        "Timestamp": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "Signature": "EXAMPLE",
        "SigningCertUrl": "EXAMPLE",
        "MessageId": "95df01b4-ee98-5cb9-9903-4c221d41eb5e",
        "Message": "{\"create-time\": \"yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss+00:00\", \"synctoken\": \"0123456789\", \"md5\": \"98f21d3824c3b2a4553315bcb0209c69\", \"url\": \"https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json\"}",
        "Type": "Notification",
        "UnsubscribeUrl": "EXAMPLE",
        "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:EXAMPLE",
        "Subject": "TestInvoke"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks !